# Getting an hibernate object throws ObjectNotFoundException

Tags: hibernate, null

Having the following domain class:

```
public class MyClass{

private MySecondClass mySecondClass;
………….

}
```

I have an `ObjectNotFoundException`, and when I get a MyClass object from database using `get()` method (`getSessionFactory().getCurrentSession().get(getType(), id)`), try to use mySecondClass’s getter in it and access any of its getters. That happens when mySecondClass object is supposed to be null but it is a proxyfied class named something javaassist.
What should be the reason for mySecondClass object coming proxied instead null, or how could I ensure that is null, so I don't need to have a exception thrown to know that?

Comment: That probably shows that your database is in an incoherent state: you have a foreign key referencing a non-existing row. Fix your data, and enable foreign key constraints to make sure it never happens again. If that's not the case, the post the exception stack trace, the code of the entity, the code that causes the exception, and the contents of the relevant rows in the database.

Comment: You're right. The foreign key was set as not null, so when it's value should be null the database changed it to 0.